# Best way to create interactive SVG HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, svg

I've been tasked with creating an interactive, visual version of an HTML form.

Workers rate their proficiency between 1 (poor) to 5 (excellent) in various areas:

```
Client Management:

[x] 1 (Poor)
[ ] 2 (OK)
[ ] 3 (Good)
[ ] 4 (Great)
[ ] 5 (Excellent)
```

Instead of just using radio buttons, however, the idea is that they're visualised in the form of a polar grid.

Each slice of the pie represents an area of ability (working with clients, for instance), and each segment of the slice indicates the user's proficiency in it. [This is a 3D representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O05b6.jpg).

The user will be able to select one segment per area of ability, equivalent to 1-5, then eventually submit it as if it were a form. I've started by creating an SVG in Illustrator and adding classes to manipulate it with JS/jQuery. Then I've used these classes to fill out a set of hidden radio buttons so I have a way to actually submit the data.

[**It works**](http://files.jayfreestone.com/overflow-chart/).

However there **must be a less DIY way of creating and interacting with the SVG** that would be better for maintainability. For instance, if I wanted to add a new segment I would have to re-create the graphic in Adobe Illustrator and add a new set of classes to the file (as well as re-add the old ones to the new output).

What's the best way to tackle this kind of interactive SVG from a maintainability perspective?

Comment: Create the SVG using DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG is not a form technology so you're not going to find anything perfect. And while I consider just about anything with d3 to be DIY, this is a very decent use-case ([see examples gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)).

You could probably do it in about 50 lines of d3 code or so. Maybe less.

As Robert's comment implies this is technically creating the svg using the DOM, however using d3 is a much nicer way to go about it than doing it manually.

I'll note that d3 is to svg almost like jquery is to html (its actually useful with html as well but the use case is more common with svg). Similarly to jQuery, you can start using d3 almost right away, but the more time you invest in learning it and "getting it" the more awesome benefits you will reap.

Comment: Thanks! d3 looks great, but is it still relevant if I'm not dealing with 'data' or charts? What I'm creating *looks* like a chart, but doesn't contain variable information. I would essentially be drawing pie-shaped buttons, and I'm not sure if a graphing library is overkill.

Comment: But you are dealing with data! The width and height of each slide is a function of how many slices you want and how many levels you want for each. The data is the number of levels you want and the description and colors for each.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you end up implementing it with d3, you might consider posting to [the codereview stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for a review of specifics.

Answer (score 0):

There are several JavaScript libraries to create, manipulate and animate SVG. The most known are RaphaëlJS (http://raphaeljs.com) and Snap.svg (http://snapsvg.io). RaphaëlJS is working even on legacy browsers like IE6 by VML fallback. Snap.svg is  designed specifically for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Applying JavaScript to an SVG is no different than applying it to HTML. An SVG is a code-based image, drawn when rendered by the browser based upon the code of the SVG file. You can incorporate the file directly into the page, or embed it. Then, you just have to apply the JavaScript to the element of the SVG as you would an element in HTML.

First, go into the SVG file (assuming it's separate from the page) and add whatever identifier you want to use (`class` or `id`).

Second, write your JavaScript as if it were nothing but another HTML element you wanted to manipulate. So, if you want something to happen when the mouse hovers over a section, then write it was if you wanted that to happen to a button and substitute the button for the target SVG element.

**Edit**:
As noted from the comments to my response, even through embedding the SVG, the DOM will treat it separately, which is why you should include the SVG code directly from this.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2axp916d/) demonstrating adding the code directly to the page. If you mouseover the mouth, it'll turn red.

If you add the SVG into the page as an `img`, it'll render as an image and the JavaScript won't work. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3ksyg0g/) to demonstrate that.

However, if you use `object` or `embed`, the JavaScript can still work on it. Here's a working example of the five primary methods of adding an SVG: http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html

As for easily modifying the SVG, it's either via the code (in a text editor) or a GUI editor (like Illustrator). So long as you have the original file, there shouldn't be in issue with editing it, but there's no "easy" way to do it. One of the nice things about SVG is that it is, entirely, a programmable image. Sure, it's nice to be able to design it visually, that's what web designers do for websites, but if you want to "really" work with it, you need to work with the code.

I'm sorry if it's not the answer you were looking for, but I do hope this helps to clears things up.

Comment: I think one little gotcha with that is that while JavaScript can access the SVG elements, it does treat the SVG as a separate "document" (like an iframe, without security). That just means rather than document.getElementById, you might need `document.getElementById('mySvg').getElementById(...`. Without this, people couldn't easily embed the same SVG twice.

Comment: This is what I've done [thus far](http://files.jayfreestone.com/overflow-chart/). I've embedded (included) it with PHP and I'm just manipulating it with jQuery/JS by adding classes to it.

Comment: @jfree I understand where you're coming from, but there is no easy solution. The SVG is the SVG, the nice thing about them is that if you have the SVG file, you have all the code already there. With that, you don't have to recreate the image, just reopen it and edit it.